# php list directly to array

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the code I have now.

```
$Top3Things = explode(';',$Top3Things);
foreach($Top3Things as $key => $Thing)
    $Top3Things[$key] = explode('|',$Thing);
```

I know that explode return an indexed array. But I thought there is a function I can put explode into and pass the names that will return an associative array.

I know this is not the answer but here is an example of what I'm looking for.

```
$Top3Things[$key] = (list($type,$size,$weight) = explode('|',$Thing));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `array_combine()`.

```
<?php
$keys = ['type', 'size', 'weight'];
$values = explode(';', $Top3Things);
$combinedArray = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel better now.